# Is it linear Time Complexity of Bigger?

Tags: algorithm, iteration, time-complexity

Can any one tell me what is the worst time complexity of below code?
Is it linear or bigger?

```
void fun(int[] nums){
{
  int min = min(nums);
  int max = max(nums);
  for(int i= min; i<=max;i++){
    print(i); //constant complexity for print
  }
}
int min(int[] nums);//return min in nums in linear time
int max(int[] nums);//return max in nums in linear time
```

where
0 <= nums.length <= 10^4 and -10^9 <= nums[i] <= 10^9

Can I say that time complexity of this code is **O(Max(nums[i]) - Min(nums[i]))** and can I say, this is **linear** time complexity?

Comment: What other time complexities do you think it might possibly be?  What is the time complexity of the `min` and `max` functions?  You say nothing about whether your data is already sorted or not.  Are you trying to consider the `print` calls in your time complexity too?

Comment: array is unsorted, and not considering print statement complexity. For ex. array =[1,200,2,6,4,100]. In this case we can find min and max in linear time(O(n) where n is length of array). Now, my for loop complexity is O(200) or O(n^3) which is much more than length of array. Can I still say its linear complexity.

Comment: The answer by @derpischer looks correct to me. But note that you've made a dubious assumption that `print(i)` is O(1) since it outputs log_10(i) characters.

Comment: As it is linear wit respect to the range `R = max - min` of the data, I would call it a *pseudo-linear* complexity. `O(N + R)` Look at this: [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range of numbers is constant (ie `-10^9 <= nums[i] <= 10^9`) then

```
for(int i= min; i<=max;i++){
  print(i); //constant complexity for print
}
```

is in *O(1)*, ie constant because you know, it iterates at most `2 * 10^9` numbers, regardless of how many numbers there are in the `nums[]` array. Thus it does not depend on the size of the input array.

Consider the following input arrays

```
nums = [-10^9, 10^9];  //size 2
nums = [-10^9, -10^9 + 1, -10^9 + 2, ..., 10^9 - 2, 10^9 - 1, 10^9]  //size 2 * 10^9 + 1
```

for both `min` and `max` will have the same values `-10^9` and `10^9` respectively. Thus your loop will iterate all numbers from `-10^9` to `10^9`. And even if there were 10^100000 numbers in the orginal array, the `for` loop will at most iterate from  `-10^9` to `10^9`.

And you say `min()` and `max()` are in *O(n)*, thus your overall algorithm would also be in *O(n)*. But if you then take into account that the given maximum length (10^4) of the array is by magnitudes smaller then the limit of your numbers, you can even neglect calling `min` and `max`

And as for your comment

> For ex. array =[1,200,2,6,4,100]. In this case we can find min and max in linear time(O(n) where n is length of array). Now, my for loop complexity is O(200) or O(n^3) which is much more than length of array. Can I still say its linear complexity

The size of the array and the values in the array are completely independent of each other. Thus you cannot express the complexity of the `for` loop in terms of `n` (as explained above). If you really want to take into account also the range of the numbers, you have to express it somehow like this  *O(n + r)*  where *n* is the size of the array, and *r* is the range of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As the complexity is linear with respect to the range `R = max - min` of the data, I would call it a **pseudo-linear** complexity. O(N + R).

This is detailed in this Wikipedia entry: [Pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)

As mentioned in the introduction of this article:

> In computational complexity theory, a numeric algorithm runs in pseudo-polynomial time if its running time is a polynomial in the numeric value of the input (the largest integer present in the input)—but not necessarily in the length of the input (the number of bits required to represent it), which is the case for polynomial time algorithms.

Generally, when analysing the complexity of a given algorithm, we don't make any specific assumption about the inherent range limitation of a particular targeted language, except of course if this is especially mentionned in the problem.